# 1st loop in table differs from the rest

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I am getting a query from a database and displaying it into a table, at the end of each row I create a button with the value of the UID (this will allow me to edit each row).

When the results are displayed the button in row 1 does not go to the form processing page, but row 2 onwards does. Ive used google chromes debugger and found the first row shows the button but it is not contained within a form like the rest of them.

Table Population on index.php

```
$admin = false;
if($user == "admin"){
    $admin = true;
}

$currstr = "";
if(mysql_num_rows($currresult) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($currresult)){
        $currstr .= '<tr style="background-color:'.tablecolour($row[3]).'">
            <td class="tid">'.$row[0].'</td>
            <td class="ttype">'.typeoptiontext($row[1]).'</td>
            <td class="tdesc">'.$row[2].'</td>
            <td class="tprio">'.prioritytext($row[3]).'</td>
            <td class="tdead">'.dateformat($row[4]).'</td>';
        if($admin){
            //$currstr .= '<td class="topt"><button name="e'.$row[0].'" value="'.$row[0].'">E</button>   <button name=c"'.$row[0].'" value="'.$row[0].'">C</button></td>';
            $currstr .= '<td class="topt"><form action="edit_task.php" method="get"><button type="submit" name="id" value="'.$row[0].'">E</button></form></td>';
        }
        $currstr .= '</tr>';
    }
}
else{
    $currstr .= '<tr><td colspan=7>NO TASKS AVAILABLE</td></tr>';
}
```

All the data recieved from the database and the button itself is shown correctly, there is nothing missing there. The problem seems to be that the button on row 1 isnt placed within a form like the rest.

The image shows the developers console in chrome, the highlighted row is the row with the problem. This is generated from the code above. I have blacked out the text content, no code.

[image]

I am not sure where the problem lies as its all working except for row 1

Comment: seems that you are assign  always the same id to all the button ... the id mus be unique

Comment: @scaisEdge I didnt spot that, as i dont need the id there anymore ive removed it but I still have the same problem when the buttons dont have id's

Comment: i don't see nothings of strange .. you should see the same value ..in the tid classed  div .. ..but what's the content of $row[0] .?.. just a sample ..

Comment: @scaisEdge no im stumped hence posing here. $row[0] is a integer for the UID and is a primary key (first row is 22 from mysql query). In chrome developers console inspector, the <form></form> brackets are missing from around the button but they are in every other row after the first. tdesc is text, tdead is a date, the rest are ints. all have values which are shown

Comment: you have other html code before this ?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes i echo the string within the table under the row of headers. I have page headers and code above. PHP wise above I have functions and mysql query